# How to disable atuo repeat for specific keyboard on linux, preferably from python

Tags: python, linux, keyboard, evdev

I am using the excellent [Python-evdev](http://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library for a utility that remaps keys in a certain way, similar to [at-home-modifier](https://gitlab.com/at-home-modifier/at-home-modifier-evdev/wikis/home). In the process, I am grabbing all my physical keyboards and pipe the keys to a virtual keyboard.

If possible, I would like to disable auto repeat for all grabbed keyboards, but not globally for the whole X server. What I have so far is a hack, just setting the auto repeat delay to something very large, e.g.

```
import evdev

dev = evdev.InputDevice('/dev/input/event5') # Insert your keyboard device here
dev.grab()
dev.repeat = evdev.device.KbdInfo(repeat = 300, delay = 600000)
print(dev.repeat)
dev.ungrab()
```

Funnily enough, this sets the repeat to 500 instead of 300. I tried setting the delay to 0 or -1, but this is just getting ignored. Is there any way at all to completely disable the auto-repeat, maybe using different tools?